# Annontation constraint property path

Tags: symfony, validation, constraints, entity, propertypath

I was wondering if it were possible to set something like a property path to an annontation constraint where the assertion should be applied on.

Consider this example:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Document", cascade={"persist"})
 * @Assert\Image(mimeTypes={"jpeg", "png"}, path="this.file")
 *
protected $document;
```

In this example I would like to apply the Image constraint to the file property which is a child of the Document entity with an attribute like **path="this.file"**

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: $file property is a property of Document entity ?

Comment: In this example, yes it is.

Comment: Maybe you could use Expression. Ever thinked about it ?

Comment: Would be if I could apply existing constraints to the specific property. But  it doesn't look to be possible and I'd like not to reinvent the wheel..

Comment: The problem is I don't really understand some parts of your question. It would be nice if you could post more code from your entities. For example class declaration and some important fields.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of defining dynamically the constraint in php.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Image;
// [...]
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder
        ->add('document', FileType::class, [
            'constraints' => [
               new Image([
                  'mimeTypes' => ["jpeg", "png"],
                  'path' => $anyVariable
               ])
            ],
        ]);
```

Comment: path does not exist in Image class

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own validator as explained in this [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html) and then apply to any field you want.

Hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately I'd like to use the Symfony assertions so I don't have to reinvent the wheel..